# Javascript Sub Module Method

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I recently started at an environment where the sub module method of JS programming is used exclusively throughout the application. Coming from the wild west of advertising however, I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it. I understand the concepts, which is why it's so frustrating that the following alert never fires:

```
customNamespace.anotherCustomVar = (function ($, customNamespace) { 
    return {
        init : function () {
            alert(''); // Doesn't fire
        }
    };
})( jQuery, customNamespace );
```

Looking at another file almost exactly like this, putting an alert in the init fn works fine.

```
customNamespace.aDifferentCustomVar = (function ($, customNamespace) {
    return {
        init : function () {
             alert(''); // Does fire
        }
    };
})( jQuery, customNamespace );
```

These are separate js files in the same directory fyi. Does it have something to do with my anotherCustomVar name, if aDifferentCustomVar works?

Comment: Did you call `customNamespace.anotherCustomVar.init()`?, was `customNamespace.aDifferentCustomVar.init()` called.

Comment: I did not call it, specifically b/c I'm trying to mimic the established workflow. Neither does the one that works though, at least in that file. Is it a matter of hunting down where that init is called?

Comment: The alert won't fire unless you call `init`, so it has to be called somewhere.

Comment: there's a global.js that calls all the inits - just a matter if learning this codebase I guess. Cheers!